# Unable to find delete permission in object settings for a custom profile

Tags: permissions, partner-communities, custom-profile

I would like to give delete permission on a custom profile for account object, However when I go to the profile I don't see the delete object permission, the only available are Read, create and edit.

The profile is a custom profile cloned from the Partner Profile.

Attached is the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Do you have person accounts actually enabled?

Comment: Yes the person accounts are enabled

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5),  Partner profile license will have only Read, Create, Edit permission on Account.

[image]